# Checkbox content Visibility

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to hide Checkbox content in Silverlight

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

                cb.Name = "checkboxName";

                cb.Content = 99;
```

// value that I need somewhere else, but don't want user to see it

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want content to be seen just keep it empty and use tag property to store any object.

i.e cb.tag = Anything. => this can be accessed anywhere.